# Retrieve TCP stream after connecting to target through proxy using HTTP CONNECT web request?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, networking

> Retrieve underlying TCP stream after connecting to target through proxy using HTTP CONNECT web request?

I need to establish a TCP connection to target through corporate proxy using PowerShell (or C#).

I'm using the following PowerShell code to establish a proxied connection to target (auto-configure proxy settings):

```
$destHost = '<target-ip>'
$destPort = '<port>'

# Create HTTP CONNECT request
$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("http://" + $destHost + ":" + $destPort ) 
$request.Method = "CONNECT"

# Detect and set automatic proxy and network credentials
$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
$proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$request.Proxy = $proxy

# Send HTTP CONNECT request
$serverResponse = $request.GetResponse()
```

This yields the following response from the proxy:

```
IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
Cookies                 : {}
Headers                 : {}
SupportsHeaders         : True
ContentLength           : -1
ContentEncoding         : 
ContentType             : 
CharacterSet            : 
Server                  : 
LastModified            : 30-04-2019 10:49:57
StatusCode              : OK
StatusDescription       : Connection established
ProtocolVersion         : 1.1
ResponseUri             : http://<target-ip>:<port>/
Method                  : CONNECT
IsFromCache             : False
```

Now, how can I retrieve the TCP stream for sending/receiving data to/from target?

Comment: Do search on google for following : c# codeproject ssl tls

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - You are wrong. The HTTP CONNECT request is for proxying raw TCP streams.

Comment: @Shuzheng I am wrong! Sorry. That's interesting!